# Powershell Script to Move Files, but moves the Script itself - How to Fix?

Tags: powershell, move

I have the following script to break up a large number of files in a single directory into subfolders, split up to keep the subfolder size/file count manageable. It works, but has two minor issues I'd like to fix:

```
# First count the number of files in the $OrigFolder directory
$numFiles = (Get-ChildItem -Path $OrigFolder).Count
$i=0

#Calculate copy operation progress as a percentage
[int]$percent = $i / $numFiles * 100

$n = 0; Get-ChildItem -File | Group-Object -Property {$script:n++; 
[math]::Ceiling($n/9990)} | 
ForEach-Object {                               
    $dir = New-Item -Type Directory -Name $_.Name   # Create directory
    $_.Group | Move-Item -Destination $dir          # Move files there

# Log progress to the screen
Write-Host "$($_.FullName) -> $FolderName"

# Tell the user how much has been moved
Write-Progress -Activity "Copying ... ($percent %)" -status $_  -PercentComplete             
$percent -verbose
$i++
    }
```

First, how do I prevent the script itself from moving to the first script-created subfolder?

Second, how do I prepend the name "Move Files" to the script-created folders? Right now they are just numbered sequentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclude the script itself by inspecting `$MyInvocation` like this:

```
$n = 0; Get-ChildItem -File |Where-Object {$_.FullName -ne $MyInvocation.InvocationName} | Group-Object -Property { ...
```

When you call `New-Item` to create the directory, you can pre-pend whatever you want to the `-Name` argument:

```
$dir = New-Item -Type Directory -Name "Move Files $($_.Name)"   # Create directory
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick help! But I get the following error now in the progress indicator code:

Comment: At E:\<redacted path>\move 9990 files to folders-1.ps1:19 char:10
+ $percent -verbose
+          ~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '-verbose' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Comment: Commenting out the "Write-Progress -Activity "Copying ... ($percent %)" -status $_  -PercentComplete             
$percent -verbose
$i++" code works though. Any idea why?

Comment: @ScottCoats Remove the line break between `-PercentComplete` and `$percent -verbose $i++`

Comment: For those who need the working script and don't want to work out the changes themselves, here is the working version:

Answer (score 1):

For those who need the working script and don't want to work out the changes themselves, here is the working version

```
# MOVE FILES TO FOLDERS
#
# When placed in a parent directory, this Powershell script moves a large number of files (e.g., > 10,000)
# to subdirectories in batches of xxx files. In the case here, in batches of 9,990 files to each
# subdirectory.
# Edit the item in the script ($n/9990) to change the breakpoint for your needs.
# Thanks to  Mathias R. Jessen on StackOverflow for helping with the code.
#

# BEGIN SCRIPT
# First count the number of files in the $OrigFolder directory
$numFiles = (Get-ChildItem -Path $OrigFolder).Count
$i=0

#Calculate copy operation progress as a percentage
[int]$percent = $i / $numFiles * 100

$n = 0; Get-ChildItem -File | Where-Object {$_.FullName -ne $MyInvocation.InvocationName} | Group-Object -Property {$script:n++; 
[math]::Ceiling($n/9990)} | 
ForEach-Object {                               
    $dir = New-Item -Type Directory -Name $_.Name "Move Files $($_.Name)"  # Create directory
    $_.Group | Move-Item -Destination $dir          # Move files there

# Log progress to the screen
Write-Host "$($_.FullName) -> $FolderName"

# Tell the user how much has been moved
Write-Progress -Activity "Copying ... ($percent %)" -status $_  -PercentComplete
$percent -verbose
$i++
    }

# END SCRIPT
```

Thanks to @mathias-r-jessen for his help with the code.